# If the subjects of Ymir are the descendants of Ymir, and the only race capable of turning into titans, how's that Eren doesnt have royal bloodline?

Tags: attack-on-titan

According to,

[Subjects of Ymir](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Subjects_of_Ymir)

> The Subjects of Ymir (ユミルの民 Yumiru no Tami?) are an ethnic group
> descended from Ymir Fritz and the only race that was capable of
> becoming Titans

Since Eren is capable of turning into a Titan, he has to be a descendant of Ymir Fritz.

According to,

[Founding Titan](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Founding_Titan#Royal_Bloodline_Necessity)

> Only those with royal blood—the Fritz or Reiss royal families—were
> able to use the true power of the Founding Titan

So, how is that Eren isn't of royal bloodline, if he's a descendant of Ymir Fritz, who is the first ancestor of the Ymir royal family?

Comment: Related, possibly dup: [How come not all subjects of Ymir have royal (Fritz) blood?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/61895/20275)

Answer (score 1):

Subject of Ymir doesn't mean descendants of Ymir, it means all Eldians born after Ymir's titan demise, and the ones that lived in that time.